# How can I tell precisely what is being adjusted with a preset in Apple Aperture?

Tags: post-processing, apple-aperture, presets

Take "Auto Enhance" found under "Quick Fixes" for example, I can only see that there's Enhance, Levels, and Edge Sharpen done, and no way to see the specifics, i.e. by Enhance are there any contrast or saturation changes, if so by how much.

Am I missing something or is this just simply not possible?

Comment: Lame, I tried exporting the plugin to a file and reading it in a text editor.  I can make out some things, but not everything, and its not terribly easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "lift adjustments" to see the details of any adjustments to the image.

For example, after doing "Auto Enhance", the lift adjustments HUD shows:

Enhance: Vibrancy (0.20)

Levels: Auto Levels

Edge sharpen: Intensity (0.50), Edges (0.22), Falloff (0.69)

Answer (score 0):

If there are changes to any of the settings you should be able to see them on the panel. Some things like auto enhance will just be the the sharpening and contrast, whereas some more advanced ones will be also alter the colours and the curves and any of the others of hundreds of options. you would have to apply the preset and then have a look through all the options to see  what it has done.

As far as I understand, there is no way to easily see what has been done. I imagine that some of the adjustments are dynamic so will only adjust the curves to a certain level so that clipping is avoided etc.

@Shizam Could you post up some of the text file. It may be that it is just laid out in an awkward format.

Comment: Where can I find the text file?

Comment: Sorry I meant to direct that to @Shizam. I don't have aperture on this computer so I will have to wait until I get home to try and extract it, and see what the structure is